# Обработка события при вводе в TextField

Tags: javafx, jtextfield

Как обработать событие при вводе каждой буквы в TextField(JavaFX)?
У меня есть кнопка и TextField. Кнопка неактивна. Хочу что бы при вводе он проверил не состоит ли строка из пробелов и тогда сделал кнопку активной.

Answer (score 1):

```
textField.textProperty().addListener( (ov,oldV,newV) -> {
    if ( !newV.trim().isEmpty() ) {
        button.setDisable( false );
    }
} );
```

P.S. Это для `javafx.scene.control.TextField`, хотя в тегах указан `jTextField`.

Comment: Помогло! спасибо! да, мне нужен TextField, ошибся в тегах.